# ASP.NET Listview changing image size before loading page

Tags: asp.net, image, listview

i have Listview with images in my page. In DB I store info about image link and shape of an image (rectangle/square). Is it possible to change width of an image if stored value for shape is "rectangle" and how to do it? Thanks

Comment: What you have tried?? Post your code...

Comment: i am not sure, but i think it was possible to do it in prerender, i just forgot how. If i know the id, i should be able to get the shape of id from database and than change the size.